# with ggplot2 (3.2.0) update ggsave gives Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (25)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, version, facet-grid

I had code that worked with ggplot2 v. 3.1.0 until I updated ggplot2 to its current version (3.2.0, as of 7/25/2019).

Though the plot runs without an error, I cannot save it with ggsave. ggsave throws an error: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (25): label

I don't understand why it worked before and won't work now. I know it has to do with the faceting because the plot that aggregates all my data still runs. Below is the dataset in its entirety:

```
problem <- tibble(standing = c("Good Standing", "Good Standing", "Good Standing", "Good Standing", "Good Standing", "Overdue", "Overdue", "Overdue", "Overdue", "Overdue"),
                  class = c("English", "Science", "Math", "Psychology", "Gym", "English", "Science", "Math", "Psychology", "Gym"),
                  n = c(884, 1973, 2160, 2096, 2262, 374, 623, 771, 564, 1041),
                  prop = c(70, 76, 74, 79, 68, 30, 24, 26, 21, 32),
                  num = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

Here's the code for the plot. This runs successfully:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
color_palette <- c("#000099", "#CC0099")


problem_Plot <- ggplot(problem_data, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = standing)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(n, ",\n", " ", prop, "%")), color = "white", size = 6, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette) +
  theme_void() +
  xlim(.5, 2.5) +
  annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0.5, y = 0, label = paste0(problem_data$prop[problem_data$standing == 'Good Standing'], "%"), fontface = "bold", size = 16, color = "#000099") +
  ggtitle(paste0("School Status Report by Subject: ", month(today(), label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE), " ", year(today()), "\n")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold", hjust = .5, vjust = -.5)) +
  labs(fill = "standing") +
  facet_grid(. ~class) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))
```

Last, here's the ggsave line that throws the aesthetic error. Make sure to run this with ggplot2 v 3.2.0, as this same exact line worked in v 3.1:

```
library(ggplot2) #make sure it is version 3.2.0

ggplot2::ggsave(paste0("Problem Plot", today(), ".png"), plot= problem_Plot, width = 20, height = 5, units = "in")
```

Any solutions to get it to work again with this current version will be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is not an issue with ggsave, the problem is with your plot: it also won't render outside of ggsave. If you remove the annotate call, it should be fine.

Comment: @teunbrand , but unfortunately I need the annotation call, or, at least, I need what it’s supposed to put on the plot.

Comment: Can't you reformulate the annotation as a geom? Perhaps with an `inherit.aes = FALSE`?